# QGIS how to draw a circular polyline?

Tags: qgis, line

I would like to draw a semi-circular pattern (arc) on QGIS as a polyline. I did it before but have no idea how I achieved it. I am on QGIS 3.16.4.

I would like to replicate the black arc lines called "Pendulum_transect_compared" on my image: [image]

Once these lines are created, I intend to use "QChainage" to generate linearly-spaced points along these arcs.

Comment: Try Digitize with curve tool from Advanced Digitizing Toolbar. You will need to add the toolbar under View menu -> Toolbars.

Comment: It might also be possible to utilize SpatiaLite and the MakeArc function https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html#p0 `will return a LINESTRING approximating the Circular Arc defined by cx, cy and radius; the arc's extremities will be defined by start, stop angles expressed in degrees.`